# Safe and easy way to upgrade from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.3?

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
```

We have recently installed Magento 2.4.2-p1, then migrated our data from Magento 1.9.4 and installed the Magento Porto theme and had Amasty isntall their extensions. Is there a safe and easy way to upgrade from our Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.3? I don't want to loose the functionality of our extensions.

Comment: use below command your existing extension will not get effect

Comment: @ Gohil Rajesh Thank you very much for that. What are the chances this will crash the website, the theme or the installed extensions? Thank you again. Is this something you recommend I would do?

Comment: @Allysin I would advice to wait for some sometime before upgrading
to  2.4.3 . This version is new and lately magento's new versions have lot of  bugs. Whatever any one says no one knows how the third party module will behave in new version. I have suffered same thing for 2.4.2  I have upgraded it from 2.4.1  to 2.4.2 and most of the third party of well known vendor extension were producing bugs. My personal experience is this always go with a version or two less than the new version as it is more settled and bug free than new version with magneto.

Answer (score 2):

> *)set developer mode
>
> 1. php bin/magento -d memory_limit=6G  maintenance:enable
> 2. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3
>    --no-update
> 3. composer update or upload composer.phar in root and run php -d
>    memory_limit=6G composer.phar update
> 4. rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/*
>    pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*
> 5. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> 6. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> 7. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> 8. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> 9. php bin/magento cache:clean
> 10. php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:
>
> 13. php bin/magento --version
> 14. php bin/magento maintenance:disable
> 15. Php version set 7.4 via cpanel or htaccess

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for that. What are the chances this will crash the website, the theme or the installed extensions? Thank you again.

Comment: @allysin you are already on latest version 2.4.2-p1. so look like no any chance to crash website, everything should work properly

Comment: I advice to take database and source backup before upgrade

Comment: Thank you Gohil, I will do that then. Fingers crossed :-)

Comment: Yeah..good luck

Comment: Don't simply take a backup. First run the update on your staging/UAT/test environment and do a full end-to-end test of any business critical functionality, especially payment processing.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would wait it out. I'm one week into migrating to 2.4.3 from 2.4.2-p1 and there are ton of issues, especially with the plugins from vendors.

Just upgrade to 2.4.2-p2 and give it a month or two.

And yes, you can upgrade and its not super difficult to do so.

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update
```

Remove anything in your **replace section** and then

```
composer update
rm -rf var/generation var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend generated/code
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```

UPDATE:

FYI do not update your Production server without testing the upgrade on DEV. That would be a disaster! There are just too many things that could go wrong and too many bugs that are present even in a newly released version.